# Drawing a rectangle in an oval

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, photoshop

Hear me out before someone suggests this should be moved to [stack maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/). I'd like to someone to double check my aging trig calculation to draw a rectangle within an oval in Photoshop using JavaScript.

I have a circle where I want to know the length of W and H.

[image: circle]

That's easy:

> W = 2 (cos θ/r)
>
> H = 2 (sin θ/r)

r is the radius of the circle.

What I need to know is the length of W and H for an oval.

[image: oval]

Here are a few considerations:

- H is the same value in both cases. But obviously θ changed accordingly.
- The width of the oval can be considered x times wider than the 2r.
- The chords, W and H are always horizontal and vertical respectively).
- The oval can be considered to be just a wider version circle and not an ellipse.

So would W be

> W = 2x (cos θ/r)?

I don't need it to be super accurate (1 decimal place) as ultimately I will be drawing a rectangle within an oval and 1 pixel difference is not going to be noticed.

And the code to draw the oval:

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

var w = 120;
var h = 50;
selectThis(10,10,w, h);

function selectThis(top, left, right, bottom)
{
    // =======================================================
    var id1 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id2 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    var id3 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
    var id4 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
    ref1.putProperty( id3, id4 );
    desc1.putReference( id2, ref1 );
    var id5 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id6 = charIDToTypeID( "Top " );
    var id7 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id6, id7, top );
    var id8 = charIDToTypeID( "Left" );
    var id9 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id8, id9, left );
    var id10 = charIDToTypeID( "Btom" );
    var id11 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id10, id11, bottom );
    var id12 = charIDToTypeID( "Rght" );
    var id13 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id12, id13, right );

    var id14 = charIDToTypeID( "Elps" );
    desc1.putObject( id5, id14, desc2 );
    var id15 = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" );
    desc1.putBoolean( id15, true );

    executeAction( id1, desc1, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: Actually the triangle of both the circle and the oval have the following formula for width and height which are `x + Δx = (r + Δr) cos (t)` and `y + Δy = (r + Δr) sin(t)`, which in the circle case the `Δw = Δh = Δr = 0`. So the formula for oval is quite complex since it involves two other variables for vertical and horizontal scale

Comment: There is infinite number of rectangles inscribed in ellipse. What specific one do you need?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: @beaker feel free to close it if you feel that's the right thing to do.

Comment: @GhoulFool My comment was auto-generated when I voted to close with a custom reason. If two other voters agree with me, the question will be closed. If not, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the formula of circle and oval in term of r and theta is defined as

**Circle:**

[image: Circle Formulae]

**Oval:**

[image: Oval Formulae] 
Given a and b the scale of horizontal and vertical dimension respectively.

And consider the following triangle assuming the triangle is inside the circle/oval

[image: Triangle]

For circle, as θ changes, radius (r) will not change since it is constant and Δr will be 0 thus Δx and Δy will also produce 0. For oval however is different and both equation derived into their derivative which produce as below

[image: Derivative] where a = b = 1 for circle

So, the new triangle width and height will become as follows:

[image: New size]

Which width **(W)** and height **(H)** can be obtained by doubling the **x + Δx** and **y + Δy** respectively.